# How to use ArcGIS WPF Runtime Deployment Tool via Command Line?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, wpf, arcgis-runtime, deployment, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I'd like to be able to use the WPF Runtime (10.1.1) Deployment tool via the command line. If I run DeploymentTool.exe /? on the command line, I get the dialog in the attached image. The /c option indicates support for using a config file. I cannot find documentation on the config file format. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Apparently when you create a configuration in the tool, it is stored in the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\ArcGIS Runtime SDK\Settings. If any additional information is stored elsewhere, I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Branscomb answered this question for me in the ArcGIS forums at http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/84123-Use-Runtime-Deployment-Tool-via-Command-Line ...

"*Configurations are created by the Runtime Deployment Tool in C:\Users\\Documents\ArcGIS\Runtime Configurations.*"

I'll add that it's an XML file so the parameters are easily discoverable & interpreted.